# Jupyter Notebook Config file when using JupyterHub

Tags: laptop, jupyter

We have a JupyterHub setup for which the cofig lives at /etc/JupyterHub/jupyterhub_config.py

I have still not been able to identify the config file for Jupyter Notebook in this scenario. Doing

```
$jupyter --paths
```

leads me to this

```
config:
    /home/srivya/.jupyter
    /anaconda/envs/py35/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/srivya/.local/share/jupyter
    /anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /run/user/662252109/jupyter
```

I have already modified the setting in all the files listed in the config section, but it still doesn't effect the Notebooks.

We are trying to change the NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit in the config file but have been unable to do so for our notebooks.